# What does high fault coverage digital vector at an IC module mean?

Tags: integrated-circuit, test, specifications

I'm reading some specification docs on some integrated circuits and I came a cross this definition which I'm trying to understand.

> This provide the capability of running high fault coverage digital
>   vectors at IC module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fault coverage is the percentage of the logic gates on a digital (part of) an IC which can be tested. So a 90 % fault coverage means that 90 % of the gates can be tested and 10 % cannot.

Of course 100 % fault coverage is ideal but this is not always feasible.

This test is done using test vectors which are patterns of ones and zeros which are fed into the IC usually via a JTAG port.

Such a test is performed by the IC's manufacturer in order to guarantee proper operation of the IC.

Comment: I don't mean to be splitting hairs.  But testing each gate is not 100% coverage.  100% fault coverage is testing 100% of the PATHS.  A gate may be involved in many, many paths.  For example consider 8:1 mux; you would need to test every possible input->output pair for 100% coverage.  As another example consider a NAND gate with one pullup PMOS open, which could be missed if you only test each gate individually (since the other PMOS is still working, depending your vector, it could make the gate look okay)

Answer (score 1):

A "vector" is simply an arrangement of inputs. So when fully decoded, the blurb means:

> This provides the ability to test the IC using a large variety of inputs

But marketspeak and Chinglish result in the original blurb.

Answer (score 1):

Fault coverage refers to the %-age of total **arcs** which are tested.  This can be done either in post-silicon testing (automatic test pattern generation, built in self-test, etc) to check for defects in the fabricated circuit, or as part of formal verification (checking the circuit implementation versus the register-transfer-level description of the circuit) during the earlier design stages.

An arc is defined as a unique path from a rising/falling edge at an input port to a rising/falling edge at the output port, along with each internal node along the way (rising or falling).

An inverter has two arcs; in(r)->out(f) and in(f)->out(r).

Consider the CMOS NAND gate:

[image: cmos nand]

The 2-input NAND gate has 4 arcs:

- a(r)->out(f) for b=1
- a(f)->out(r) for b=1
- b(r)->out(f) for a=1
- b(f)->out(r) for a=1

You cannot just check each gate once, but need to cover each arc.

As a further example using the 2-input NAND case, suppose the wire is open between Vdd and the PMOS connected to input B.

Now, if you A rises (0->1) while holding B=1, you would see the output fall, and conclude that the gate works. But, the gate will not work in the case of B falling (since the PMOS B controls is broken).

As you create more complex, multi-stage logic, the number of arcs needed for 100% fault coverage increases exponentially.  So, it is not always possible.